compact and trace operator
I am study compact and trace classes of operators in Hilbert space. To clarify, I asked the following question, but have not been able to resolve it yet. Consider $L_p \left( \mathbb{R}^d \right) $ and operator $A f(x) = g(x) f(x)$, $A:~ L_p \left( \mathbb{R}^d \right) \to L_p \left( \mathbb{R}^d \right)$ where $g(x)$ is some function. For the operator $A$ to be continuous, it is sufficient for the function $g(x)$ to be bounded. What sufficient and necessary conditions for the function $g(x)$ can be specified for the operator $A$ to be compact or for there to be  operator $A$ with a trace

Try to determine the spectrum of $T.$ You will see the operator is never compact unless $g=0.$

Clarification: you need $g$ to be bounded (almost everywhere) and measurable.
Here are some steps you can take:

Show that $\sigma(A)$ is the essential range of $g$

Show that $A$ is selfadjoint and conclude that if $A$ is nonzero and compact then it has a nonzero eigenvalue.

Show that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $A$ if and only if $g$ takes the value $\lambda $ on a set of positive measure.

Show that the eigenspace for $\lambda$ is infinite-dimensional.

Conclude that $A$ is compact if and only if $g=0$.


